# Open Command prompt through chrome

Tags: google-chrome, local-files, external-application

Is it possible to open a command prompt through chrome link/button and passing a value/url. I am looking for a solution to open a local file through chrome. I am okay if the user manually presses the run command to open but alteast the cmd should open with passed values.